# Are power analyses of logistic regressions the same whether it is is one variable or multiple?

Tags: r, logistic, statistical-power

I conducted power analyses of a single logistic regression using the R WebPower package as such

```
library(WebPower)
M1 <- glm(trait ~ ancestry, dataset, family = binomial)
p0 = exp(M1$coefficients[1])/(1+exp(M1$coefficients[1]))
p1 = exp(sum(M1$coefficients))/(1+exp(sum(M1$coefficients)))
wald <- wp.logistic(n=number, p0=p0, p1=p1, family="Bernoulli")
```

I am now working on a multiple logistic regression
`M1 <- glm(trait ~ PC1 + PC2, dataset, family = binomial)`, so I am wondering, is there anything that I need to change for the power analysis?

WebPower seemingly only has one function for logistic regressions (https://rdrr.io/cran/WebPower/man/wp.logistic.html). Nothing specifies whether it is single or multiple.